# MongoDB - Is there a way to perform $set on a hash without overwriting existing/unreferenced key/values?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Let's say I have a document like this:

```
{
  _id: "12345",
  hash_field: {
    "foo": "bar"
  }
}
```

And at some point, without knowing what the value of this document's `hash_field` is, I need to add some more key/value pairs to it while leaving the current intact. I'm looking for a way to do this without wiping the existing data, and without having to make multiple nested updates

```
db.myCollection.updateOne({_id:"12345"}, 
                          {'$set': { 
                            hash_field: { 
                              "key1": "value1", 
                              "key2": "value2"
                            }
                          }
                          })
```

The above will wipe the `{"foo":"bar"}`.

I know I can do two separate $set calls with `'$set': {"hash_field.key1": "value1"}` and `'$set': {"hash_field.key2": "value2"}` but I'm looking for a way to do this in one mongo update. Possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`$mergeObjects`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/).

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: "12345"
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      hash_field: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          "$hash_field",
          {
            "key1": "value1",
            "key2": "value2"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Xy-FoclTfr-)